# Angular 6: one main protected parent route with module

Tags: angular, routes

We are currently building an administration application using Angular 6. We barely started but want to apply bests practices early on and want to use the optimal structure and modularity that suits us bests. For that, we decided to handle routes per module (don't want to have a bloated single file) with the use of `RouterModule.forRoot` and `RouterModule.forChild`.

Being an administration, we want the all application to be protected (using a Guard). However we are facing an issue regarding parent route and children when it comes of modularity in routes.

Let's say, we have a main `AppRoutingModule` that contains the following:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: []
  },
  { path: 'oauth/callback', component: AuthComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Now let's say we have another module, the `UsersRoutingModule` which contains:

```
const usersRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/users',
    component: UsersComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(usersRoutes)
  ]
})
export class UsersRoutingModule {}
```

How can we define routes in modules such as the above become the equivalent of this:

```
[
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'oauth/callback', component: AuthComponent }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you are doing it right so don't worry, the best practice (as far as I know) is to separate each bigger (logically connected) code chunk in a separate module (for example- `administration.module`, `dashboard.module`, `shopping-cart.module`, ....). Each module must have it's **own routing module** (like the second snippet that you had posted) and all of those module must be **lazily loaded in their parent** routing module.

```js
// App.module
//** Some imports */
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}

// App.routing-module

//** Some imports */

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // Lazy loaded module
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    loadChildren: 'app/crisis-center/crisis-center.module#CrisisCenterModule'
  }
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [CanDeactivateGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}


//** crisis-center.module/
//** Some imports */
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    CrisisCenterRoutingModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class CrisisCenterModule {}

//** crisis-center.routing
//** Some imports */
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Some-wrap-component,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: Some-component
      }
    ]
  }
];
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(crisisCenterRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})
export class CrisisCenterRoutingModule { }
```

If your `Admin.module` is very big, you can separate the logic form it to more modules for example (`manage-users.module`, `manage-projects.module`, ...) and again you can use the lazy loading strategy.

P.S. Most of the code is from the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration), I hop this helped you, also I advice you to look at the different `preloadingStrategy` if you want to implement all best routing practices :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I kinda get what I need to do. However, I still don't know how I can implement a global guard for all routes (don't want to implement one for every modules, just one for the entire application). Any idea ?

Comment: Ahh I gotcha ya, just add the guard once on root level of the module which you want to guard, for example if you want to have the guard on `CrisisCenterModule ` module, add the guard on the path that is leading to the module (`crisis-center` in the example), this guard will be triggered the first time you try to access some of this path `children` or the path itself. If you want to trigger it more than once you can look at this : https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers (I hope that i got the question this time :D)